# Windows server 2008: Shares slow to show up

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

We have a windows service that runs fine on Windows 2003, but I have noticed that on 2008 it does not work the same.  One of the things it does when it starts up is checks if a couple folder locations are present.  For example, on a server named 'Test', I might check if \Test\ServerShare is present and if not, create it.  The folder is there and it is accessible by the time I log on, but when the machine is rebooted and the service starts, it can't find it.  I was going to make the service sleep for 30 seconds or so when it starts but that seems so kludgey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the service to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" instead of "Automatic".  It's probably starting before the server service has finished starting.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, thanks Denny!